# range in negative steps starting from negative not appearing in list

Tags: python, list

I have a code where the positive numbers are fine, but the negatives aren't working.

I tried printing the `x= range(-1 , n , -1)` part, when I input a negative `n` to check what's wrong all it does is:

print [-1, -5 , -1] when I input e.g -5

Can anyone check my code for what's wrong

```
n = int(input("enter a number:"))

if n>=0:
  x = range(int(1),n)
  list_1 = [x+1 for x in range(n)]
  list_1.insert(0,"m")
  list_2 = [x+2 for x in range(n)]
  list_2.insert(0,"m+1")
  list_3 = [(x+1) ** (x+2) for x in range(n)]
  list_3.insert(0,"m**(m+1)")
  list_of_lists = [list_1, list_2, list_3]


  for a in zip(*list_of_lists):
        print(*a, sep = '\t', end = '\n')

elif n<0:
    x = range(-1,n,-1)
    list_1 = [x+1 for x in range(n)]
    list_1.insert(0,"m")
    list_2 = [x+2 for x in range(n)]
    list_2.insert(0,"m+1")
    list_3 = [(x+1) ** (x+2) for x in range(n)]
    list_3.insert(0,"m**(m+1)")
    list_of_lists = [list_1, list_2, list_3]

    for a in zip(*list_of_lists):
        print(*a, sep = '\t', end = '\n')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`range(-5)` won't produce results, you need to tell it to reiterate down

```
r = range(0, n, -1)
list_1 = [x + 1 for x in r]
list_1.insert(0, "m")
list_2 = [x + 2 for x in r]
list_2.insert(0, "m+1")
list_3 = [(x + 1) ** (x + 2) for x in r]
list_3.insert(0, "m**(m+1)")
list_of_lists = [list_1, list_2, list_3]

for a in zip(*list_of_lists):
    print(*a, sep='\t', end='\n')
```

Output

```
m   m+1 m**(m+1)
1   2   1
0   1   0
-1  0   1
-2  -1  -0.5
-3  -2  0.1111111111111111
```